# Como invertir un vector 3x3 de esta forma en java

Tags: java, array

Mi intención con este código es que cuando escriba mi vector 3x3:

> 1 2 3

> 4 5 6

> 7 8 9

Le de a la opción invertir y quede así:

> 9 8 7

> 6 5 4

> 3 2 1

Pero en el código que escribí me queda así:

> 7 8 9

> 4 5 6

> 1 2 3

```
public static void invertir(int m[][]){
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length /2; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < m[1].length; j++) {
    int temp = m[i][j];
    m[i][j] = m[m.length - 1 - i][j];
    m[m.length - 1 - i][j] = temp;
   }
      System.out.println("\n");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Checa este [snippet](https://gist.github.com/JaimeMenendez/998b50af8128e73c1155b8d3d6e8375c).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un bucle for para recorrer el vector o matriz, y copiar los elementos en otro vector o matriz. Pero si sólo necesitas mostrarlo:

```
public static void invertir(int m[][]){
    for (int i = m.length; i >0 ; i--) {
      for (int j = m[1].length; j > 0 ; j++) {
      System.out.print(m[i][j]);
   }
      System.out.println("\n");
  }
 }
```

Esta es la idea. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una solucion que planteé, pero en dos metodos.
Espero te sirva, saludos.

```
public static void invertirFilas(int m[][]){
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length /2; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < m[1].length; j++) {
    int temp = m[i][j];
    m[i][j] = m[m.length - 1 - i][j];
    m[m.length - 1 - i][j] = temp;
   }
      System.out.println("\n");
  }
  invertirColumnas(m);
 }

 public static void invertirColumnas(int matriz[][]){
    for (int x=0; x < matriz.length; x++) {
        System.out.print("|");
        for (int y=matriz[x].length-1; y >=0; y--) {
          System.out.print (" "+matriz[x][y]);
        }
        System.out.println(" |");
      }
 }
```

La matriz debe ser enviada al método `invertirFilas`, el resto se hace solo.

Espero te sirva, saludos.